# Layering UIItems

Tags: iphone

How does on layer objects in a view?

I have a number of movable UIImageViews and would like to add a button which should always be a "layer" above the images.

Meaning that the images should not overlap the button when they are moved. They should move behind rather.

How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add you image views make sure that they are behind your button. You can use 1 of the following approaches for that:

1. Add them using `insertSubview:belowSubview:` method with your button as 2nd parameter
2. After adding imageViews call `bringSubviewToFront:` method with your button as parameter

Comment: Do the have to be combined or are these methods ok on their own? it reads like they both do the job but are used for different needs?

Comment: you can use just one of them - whichever you like, sorry will edit the answer to make clearer